# post_link show only result of the same category

Tags: php, wordpress, function

How can I make my previous and next links of my single project show only projects from the same category?

This the file responsible for my single project nav.

Thank you

```
<div class="s-nav">
    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="s-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'N_Th' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?></span>
    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="s-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'N_Th' ) . '</span>' ); ?></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the code will look like this .

`<?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous in category', TRUE); ?>`

see the `TRUE` this is the trick .

general structure of the function is like :

```
<?php previous_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' ); ?>
```

read more here [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link)